# Formula to find the smallest 1-10 values relative to another column which has duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns
Column A will have postcodes in (there will be duplicates)
Column B will have a unique ID
Column c will have distances in metres

I need a formula to find the top N closest Unique ID's for each postcode.

I need to be able to select how many I need for each postcode, from the top 2 to the top 10

[image: Sample Data]

I will also need the same thing to select the Top N furthest away ones.

Comment: You can sort them and can use normal filter. Or can use pivot on the data, the pivot has functions to select top n rows in descending or ascending order

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, then you can use one of the following formulas. *Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted.*

**Method One:** --> Using `LAMBDA()` helper function `SCAN()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F4</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _data, SORT(B3:D24,{1,3},HSTACK(1,H2)),
     _seq, SCAN(0,VSTACK(1,DROP(INDEX(_data,,1),-1))=INDEX(_data,,1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,1))),
     _output, FILTER(_data,1-ISNA(XMATCH(_seq,SEQUENCE(G2)))),
     VSTACK(B2:D2,_output))
```

---

Or,

**Method Two:** --> Wihtout using any `LAMBDA()` helper function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J4</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _sortByDistance, SORT(B3:D24,{1,3},HSTACK(1,H2)),
     _postCode, TAKE(_sortByDistance,,1),
     _matchingRows, UNIQUE(TOCOL(MATCH(UNIQUE(_postCode),_postCode,)+SEQUENCE(,G2,0))),
     _output, FILTER(_sortByDistance,1-ISNA(MATCH(SEQUENCE(ROWS(_sortByDistance)),_matchingRows,))),
     VSTACK(B2:D2, _output))
```

---

In both the above formulas it can be seen that I have referenced two cells viz. <kbd>G2</kbd> & <kbd>H2</kbd>, the first one serves for the number of `TOP N` rows required when its `Closest` or `Furthest`, hence the latter cell serves the purpose for the `Closest` and the `Furthest` on changing `H2` from `1` to `-1` will return the `Furthest Id's` as well.

Also we can exclude the Columns the one which is not needed by using either `INDEX()` or `CHOOSECOLS()` function. One needs to wrap the variable `_output` within one of the functions to get the desired column.

---

**Here is a demo:**

[image]

---

Since OP has not shown the expected output, so I was bit unclear on how they expect the output, therefore here is one more way, it can be accomplished using `REDUCE()` function to get a `Cross-Tabulated` Report.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F4</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _data, SORT(B3:D24,{1,3},HSTACK(1,H2)),
     _postCode, INDEX(_data,,1),
     _uniqpCode, UNIQUE(_postCode),
     IFNA(REDUCE(HSTACK(B2,D2&"-"&SEQUENCE(,G2)),_uniqpCode,LAMBDA(x,y,
     VSTACK(x,HSTACK(y,TAKE(TOROW(FILTER(INDEX(_data,,2),INDEX(_data,,1)=y)),,G2))))),""))
```

---

Comment: Great! These both work perfectly except if the distance is zero there are no results. Is there anyway you can fix that?

Comment: @FionaP so do you want to ignore the 0 and get the next min distance ? is that what you are trying to say.

Comment: I don't want to ignore the Distance if it is 0, If the minimum distance is 0 I need it included.

Comment: Also the sheet won't always have 24 rows, are you able to make it work for however many rows there are?

Comment: @FionaP well for the distance 0 it includes it, I have tried on my end and for the rows, you can convert the source data into a Table aka Structured Reference and use the formula that way it will keep working for any number of rows.

Comment: @FionaP download the file from here to see on your own: **[Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckgAkXn7i94g-cbXG?e=bT6Ijk)**

Comment: @FionaP can you please confirm whether it has worked or not and is it solved the issue for you